# Array como parâmetro de uma função

Tags: c, array

O meu programa armazena 10 números num vetor e zera os números que forem menor que 0. Estou recebendo essas duas mensagens de erro:

- Passing argument 1 of 'ZeraNegativos' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
- Expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int'

Já tentei por o "e comercial" (&) na chamada da função e o asterisco (*) no parâmetro da função para sinalizar um ponteiro, mas também não deu certo. O código abaixo:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
     void ZeraNegativos(int entrada[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
            if (entrada[i] < 0) {
                entrada[i] = 0; //zera todo número menor do que zero
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            printf("%i", entrada[i]);
        }
    }

    int main() {
        int numeros[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            scanf("%i", &numeros[i]); //armazena os números no array
        }   
        ZeraNegativos(numeros[9]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Na mensagem de erro: exibi a linha onde ocorre o erro ?

Comment: Linha 19 e linha 3.

Comment: Armazena _9_ números, não 10. O fato de começar a contar no zero, não "soma 1" na quantidade quando você declara `int numeros[9]`: você reserva espaço para 9 números. Imagine uma régua com 9 centímetros: na marca '9' você está no fim dela, não cabe mais nada. Mas você pode por algo entre as marcações '0' e '1cm' da régua: isso que significa contar os índices dos arrays a partir do 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas um erro de conceito.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 void ZeraNegativos(int entrada[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
        if (entrada[i] < 0) {
            entrada[i] = 0; //zera todo número menor do que zero
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%i", entrada[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int numeros[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        scanf("%i", &numeros[i]); //armazena os números no array
    }   
    ZeraNegativos(numeros);
    return 0;
}
```

Obs: não precisa passar o numero de array no paramento, a linguagem C sabe disso. Bastar fazer isso:  ZeraNegativos(numeros);